# Should staying-at-home period waiting for specialized project better suits me be counted as working?

Tags: salary, new-job, work-from-home

I have an agreement to start working for a job position at the beginning of this year. Although on the surface the tasks are not different to ordinary projects, I have some specialized knowledge that both me and the manager mutually agree that it's best for both sides to wait for a more specialized project better suits me. And while it is up to me to start the probation right now, I think it's best for me to wait for them to search for such project. As a result I still stay at home and communicate via emails, which is productive in my opinion. Although my replies are almost immediately, I expect to have their replies sent several days after mine. In the mean time I still learn more on the thing I specialized.

Should this period be considered as working or not when we discuss my salary? On the one hand I'm free at home doing whatever I want, and it's my decision, not theirs; on the other hand I want to advance the specialties which they need, and they still haven't found a more suitable job for me. It's also worth to mention that their starting salary is expected for newcomers, but I think it's low for my abilities. How should I approach this?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear here.  Have you actually started the new job (i.e. pulling a salary), or have you deferred the starting date until a suitable project arrives?

Comment: Do whatever you agreed to. Whether or not they have work for you to do is irrelevant if they agreed to start paying you. But if you mutually agreed to shift your start date until there's an appropriate project, that's an agreement to also not get paid until you start (implicitly, if not explicitly). If there isn't a clear written agreement, you need one ASAP (with no agreement, whether this period would be considered working time would be a question for a lawyer). In absence of an agreement, it doesn't make much sense to pay for you to do nothing nor to wait indefinitely for a paycheck.

Comment: why would you want not to start drawing a salary as soon as possible

Comment: @Snow maybe both of us are deferring the starting date. Them for saving the money, me for more freedom. On the other hand, I think we both want me to start working now. Them for side things I can provide them, me for the money. I'm not sure is this optimal for me.

Comment: @Neuromancer maybe because this is my first time application and I'm inexperienced. I'm looking for advice here

Comment: If they’re not paying you, yet, then you’re not working for them, yet. You can’t count the waiting time as time on the job.

Comment: If you don;t show up the first day and they have not agreed in writing in advance, then likely you will be considered a no show and no longer hired.

Comment: @Ooker in many countries if your not working your missing out on any credits for social security pensions etc in the UK for example only full years count for the state pension miss a month in a year and the remaining 11 months don't count

Comment: @HLGEM we still communicate via emails and there's no sign that I'm not hired anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have no experience and this is your first job - do not stay at home!

No matter you specialization, you need to show that you can get things done. It takes some time to get into the workings of any company, and time will be better spend learning them now, on the less interesting project, as you will be able to really shine later.

Advancing the specialties they need (ie learning) is something you do in your spare time - even when working for a company. This is how you will be payed more later.

Get to work - get the XP :)

Comment: How can it eat up my spare time if it's beneficial to the company?

Comment: @Ooker Although some people at the company might appreciate your show of loyalty, they will not be able to reward you for it later. Having training in a specialized skill is a good start, but it means nothing if they never get a project that needs it, and meanwhile you’re unemployed.

Comment: @Ooker your getting paid

Comment: @Neuromancer but shouldn't they pay me for the learning that they need?

Comment: If this is a project-based company, most projects' budgets contain little money for training. If you are undergoing training, that's not chargeable to a customer and the company has to eat the costs.

Comment: @mkennedy but shouldn't this cost go to the customers, and if I quit the company after the training I have to pay for them?

Comment: I feel like training is on me - productivity is on the company. Because of this we get payed very well for working on projects, having invested in our self earlier. Now, sometimes you can negotiate getting payed to learn on the job - but don't bet too much on it.

Comment: @Ooker That's the ideal, but a customer wants to pay for work done, not training someone how to do the work. In a customer's mind, the company should already have or hired someone capable or not bid/accepted the job.

Comment: @Ooker If it's knowledge specific to the customer, that is, learning the customer's systems or specific software, that could or should be part of the contract and negotiated up front.